# Sending data through a pipeline over time (TOP, SED)

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to produce an output with the top 3 processes by CPU usage produced by the top command, over the last 10 seconds. I can see what I want by launching top in interactive modem, the output of this will update every 10 seconds:

```
top -o +%CPU -d 10
```

I can send this result to the sed command through a pipeline, which will give me one reading of the result I want:

```
top -o +%CPU -d 10 | sed -n '11q;7,10p'
```

After the timespan specified with the -d flag then the command will resolve and exit. How can I specify that I want the command to be run again and a new output to be produced when the timespan is completed?

WHAT DO I EXPECT: usually the interactive mode of the top command updates its value after a certain timespan has passed, similarly I expect the "cutout" to be updated. In other words, I expect several readings to be produced instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU watch, top & sed):

```
watch -tn10 "LINES=10 top -wbn1 -o +%CPU | sed '1,6d'"
```

Watch the composed command every 10 seconds.

Comment: it's working as expected. also, not sure about this but I suspect -d 10 should still be passed to top (so that the value is computed over that precise timespan)

Comment: @maja no, the `-bn1` options run top in batch mode and once only, the time is determined by the watch command.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line ends due to the `11q` used in the `sed` script: the `q` command instructs `sed` to exit.

Moreover, you cannot use line numbers after the `|`, as `top` will generate output again and again.

With the `top` command available on the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the number of lines of the output can be specified with `LINES` environment variables when both `-b` and `-w` options are used.

Give a try to this:

```
LINES=11 top -b -o +%CPU -d 10 -w | sed -n '/^[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*[P0-9]/ {p}'
```

Comment: both removing the q option from sed and your proposed command keep the execution open, but as far as I can tell the values are never updated

Comment: the output is updated, but I'd guess there's some sort of race condition going on. the following is the output I'm seeing:

Comment: PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0    1240    932    524 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.21 init
    8 root      20   0    1248    356     20 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 init
    9 root      20   0    1256    356     20 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.45 init
   10 ldm       20   0   13928   8840   3512 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.62 bash
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND

Comment: I do not understand, and I do not reproduce: it seems there is no CR?

Comment: sorry, the breaklines are lost in the comment: instead of seeing the expected 4 lines being added to the output it seems like a random subset of them is added instead

Comment: I do not reproduce, I do not know what could lead to this behavior.

Comment: I also wouldn't know, the system is Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 operating on 8 logical threads (which should be a rather common setup)